# How to detect page zoom level in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8, zooming

Sadly I didn't a good enough solution on this [generic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers).

[The most upvoted & accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers/5078596#5078596) does't seem to work for me on IE 8.0.7601.17514 (latest). [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers/4391284#4391284) came close to working - but it is always off for me by 20%, probably because I have large fonts defined in Windows. I'm imagine I can't detect this in javascript, so this is not a solid answer as well (even though it might actually work for 95% of IE users ... I might use it as a workaround).

Is there a better, solid way to detect what the current page zoom is in IE 8?

Comment: You could try to check the ratio between screen.width, and window.innerWidth, but that only work if window is maximized. Doesn't work in FX (Mac) because it decreases screen.width if zoomed in, so I'm not sure if it work in IE

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can access it via the screen object:

```
screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI
```

and zoom  relative to default:

```
screen.systemXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI
```

untested :)

Comment: Those properties seem to be exclusive to IE :(